# C# OOP Stackoverflow exception

Tags: c#, ооп

Есть базовый класс:

```
public abstract class BaseEvent
    {
        public DateTime? InternalTs { get; init; }
        private string _hash;

        public string Hash
        {
            get
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_hash))
                    _hash = CalcHash();
                return _hash;
            }
        }
        protected virtual string CalcHash()
        {
            try
            {
                var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
                
                if (properties.Length == 0)
                    throw new Exception($"There're no any properties in {GetType().Name}");

                if (properties.All(x => false))
                    throw new Exception($"All properties was null in {GetType().Name}");
                
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                var pp = properties.Select(x => x.GetValue(this, null));
                sb.AppendJoin('_', pp);

                return Utils.CreateMD5(sb.ToString());
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Есть класс наследник:

```
public class GotOnlineEvent : BaseEvent
    {
        public int EventId { get; init; }

        public const int Id = 8;

        private int _userId;
        public int UserId
        {
            get => this._userId;
            init => _userId = -value;
        }
        public int Extra { get; init; }
        public DateTime? ExternalTs { get; init; }

    }
```

То есть, я могу вызвать следующее:
`var goe = new GotOnlineEvent(); Console.WriteLine(goe.Hash);`

Но на этапе расчета хеша я ловлю:

```
Stack overflow.
Repeat 266 times:
--------------------------------
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(System.Object, System.Object[], System.Signature, Boolean, Boolean)
   ...
   at VkServices.source.database.models.events.BaseEvent.CalcHash()
   at VkServices.source.database.models.events.BaseEvent.get_Hash()
```

*(сократил трейсбек, чтобы не убивать ваши глаза)*

`BaseEvent.GetHash()` берет все свойства класса наследника, засовывает их в строку типа:
`$1_$2_..` и берет от нее хеш `MD5`, но что-то явно пошло не так.

Comment: `CalcHash` сейчас ведь берёт все свойства, а не только "свойства класса наследника". А во все свойства входит в том числе `Hash`, на его `get` происходит вызов `CalcHash`, который...

Comment: @Regent, А, вот черт)

Comment: Раз вопрос с тэгом ооп, стоит убрать рефлексию

Answer (score 1):

Как верно указал @Regent: при вызове всех `Properties` мы вызываем и `Hash`, которая в свою очередь вызывает `CalcHash()`, что приводило к бесконечной рекурсии.

Проблема решена путем:
`var pp = properties.Where(x => x.Name != "Hash").Select(x => x.GetValue(this, null));`

Спасибо!